# Python Opencv 4.5.5 cv::getTrackbarPos error occurs in new version

Tags: python, opencv

I got an error down below:

```
    File "C:\Users\deniz\OneDrive\Desktop\Bitirme\2.dönem\Program\Composite Project22.py", line 814, in kızart
    kırmızı = cv.getTrackbarPos('Red Area Ratio','Filter')
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:862: error: (-215:Assertion failed) trackbar in function 'cv::getTrackbarPos'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\deniz\OneDrive\Desktop\Bitirme\2.dönem\Program\Composite Project22.py", line 816, in kızart
    contrast = cv.getTrackbarPos("Contrast","Filter")
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:862: error: (-215:Assertion failed) trackbar in function 'cv::getTrackbarPos'

255 127 127
```

My main problem is the code below worked fine with my old setup for python. However, ı bought a new SSD and installed the new version of python and OpenCV. I searched this topic on StackOverflow and some people fixed this problem caused by a typo but ı do not have any typos or other errors in my old version setup. Facts that this code can work on the new setup as well but functions do work but not accurately like the old version and do not output the image in the correct form.

```
def kızart(kırmızı=255,brightness=255,contrast=127):#kırmızı=255,brightness=255,contrast=127
                global effect
                global fotoolcer
                global label1
                global test
                global image1
                global effect

                brightness = cv.getTrackbarPos('Brightness','Filter')

                kırmızı = cv.getTrackbarPos('Red Area Ratio','Filter')

                contrast = cv.getTrackbarPos('Contrast','Filter')
                print(brightness,kırmızı,contrast)
                effect = pixcont(image,kırmızı,brightness,contrast)
                cv.imshow('Filtered Image', effect)
                cv.imwrite("Filtered Image.png",effect)
```

There is a function between these two code called "pixcont".

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
                # The function imread loads an image
                # from the specified file and returns it.
                if vf_iter_counter==1:
                    original = cv.imread(vf_iter_basename)

                elif vf_iter_counter==0:
                    original = cv.imread(basename)

                # Making another copy of an image.

                image = original.copy()

                # The function namedWindow creates a
                # window that can be used as a placeholder
                # for images.

                cv.namedWindow('Filter')

                # The function imshow displays an

                # image in the specified window.

                cv.imshow('Filter', original)

                # createTrackbar(trackbarName,
                # windowName, value, count, onChange)
                # Brightness range -255 to 255
                # Contrast range -127 to 127
                cv.createTrackbar('Brightness','Filter', 255,2*255,kızart)
                cv.createTrackbar('Red Area Ratio','Filter', 127,255,kızart)
                cv.createTrackbar('Contrast','Filter',127, 2 * 127,kızart)

            cv.waitKey(0)
```

It reads the trackbar fluently and ı can get the trackbar results and print them.In the old setup, the function does not start the process until ı changed the scale bar. In this version it automatically starts it.I don't understand the real problem.
P.S.:Do ı have to add OpenCV in the system path? I don't remember ı did that.
Thx.

Comment: unfortunately nowadays, `createTrackbar()` already calls your `kizart` callback function, where only 1 of 3 trackbars are already created. bad idea to use the same callback for all trackbars. maybe use a main loop instead of a callback function

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution according to Berak's advice. I split and run the function in the while loop.

> unfortunately nowadays, createTrackbar() already calls your kizart callback function, where only 1 of 3 trackbars are already created. bad idea to use the same callback for all trackbars. maybe use the main loop instead of a callback function –
> break

Solution:

```
            def dead(x):
                pass
            cv.namedWindow('Filter')
            cv.createTrackbar('Brightness','Filter', 255,2*255,dead)
            cv.createTrackbar('Red Area Ratio','Filter', 127,255,dead)
            cv.createTrackbar('Contrast','Filter',127, 2 * 127,dead)
            while True:
                if vf_iter_counter==1:
                    original = cv.imread(vf_iter_basename)

                elif vf_iter_counter==0:
                    original = cv.imread(basename)
                
                image = original.copy()
                #cv.resizeWindow('Filter',hgt,wid)
                k = cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
                if k == 27:
                    break

                kırmızı = cv.getTrackbarPos('Red Area Ratio','Filter')
                brightness = cv.getTrackbarPos('Brightness','Filter')
                contrast = cv.getTrackbarPos('Contrast','Filter')
                effect = pixcont(image,kırmızı,brightness,contrast)

                cv.imshow('Filter',effect)

                print(kırmızı,brightness,contrast)

            cv.destroyAllWindows()
```